# Replace argument on a service that inherit of another

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I tried to override an argument on a list of services with a compiler pass.

This is working fine for all of my services execpt one. This service use service inheritance :

```
pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.abstract:
        class: '%pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.abstract.class%'
        arguments:
            - '@pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.field_splitter'

pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect:
        class: '%pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect.class%'
        parent: pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.abstract
        arguments:
            - ['pim_catalog_simpleselect', 'pim_reference_data_simpleselect']
        tags:
            - { name: 'pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter' }
```

On my compiler pass if I dump my arguments like this :

```php
class MyCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $service = $container->getDefinition('pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect');
        var_dump($service->getArguments());exit;
    }
}
```

I have this :

```
/srv/pim/src/MyNamespace/PimCatalogBundle/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/MyCompilerPass.php:31:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'pim_catalog_simpleselect' (length=24)
      1 => string 'pim_reference_data_simpleselect' (length=31)
```

So I tried to replace the argument with the index 0 but I have this error :

`request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Pim\Component\Connector\ArrayConverter\FlatToStandard\Product\ValueConverter\SimpleSelectConverter::__construct() must be an instance of Pim\Component\Connector\ArrayConverter\FlatToStandard\Product\FieldSplitter, array given`

If I try to use the index 1, I have this one :
`Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\OutOfBoundsException: The argument "1" doesn't exist.`

**Have you an idea of the problem ?**

The class of the service `pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect` is this one :

```php
namespace Pim\Component\Connector\ArrayConverter\FlatToStandard\Product\ValueConverter;

use Pim\Component\Connector\ArrayConverter\FlatToStandard\Product\FieldSplitter;

class SimpleSelectConverter extends AbstractValueConverter
{
    /**
     * @param FieldSplitter $fieldSplitter
     * @param array         $supportedFieldType
     */
    public function __construct(FieldSplitter $fieldSplitter, array $supportedFieldType)
    {
        parent::__construct($fieldSplitter);

        $this->supportedFieldType = $supportedFieldType;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convert(array $attributeFieldInfo, $value)
    {
        if ('' === $value) {
            $value = null;
        }

        return [$attributeFieldInfo['attribute']->getCode() => [[
            'locale' => $attributeFieldInfo['locale_code'],
            'scope'  => $attributeFieldInfo['scope_code'],
            'data'   => $value,
        ]]];
    }
}
```

And my Compiler pass is here :

```php
class MyCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    private const SERVICES = [
        'pim_catalog.validator.constraint.attribute_type_for_option' => 0,
        'pim_catalog.comparator.attribute.option' => 0,
        'pim_api.controller.attribute_option' => 12,
        'pim_catalog.query.elasticsearch.filter.option' => 2,
        'pim_catalog.query.elasticsearch.sorter.option' => 1,
        'pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect' => 1,
        'pim_connector.array_converter.standard_to_flat.product.value_converter.simpleselect' => 1
    ];

    /**
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
       foreach (self::SERVICES as $id => $index) {
            $service = $container->getDefinition($id);

            $service->replaceArgument($index, array_merge(
                $service->getArgument($index),
                ['my_new_type']
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an issue on github : [[DI] Compiler pass : can't replace a parameter with inheritance of services](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30732)

Edit : So the solution was just to add priority on my compiler pass :

```php
$container->addCompilerPass(new TryToOverrideSubServiceParameterPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_OPTIMIZE, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect:
    class: '%pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.simpleselect.class%'
    parent: pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter.abstract
    arguments:
        - '@pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.field_splitter'
        - ['pim_catalog_simpleselect', 'pim_reference_data_simpleselect']
    tags:
        - { name: 'pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.value_converter' }
```

Since your class SimpleSelectConverter need the service as first argument and the array as second

Comment: On the original service : The first argument is a service and the second a multidimensional array of string values. I want to add a string in my multidimensional array but when I check the arguments I don't find my service (only the multidimensional array). Normaly, the `getArguments` methods should return 2 arguments (one service and one array) but not here...

Comment: this is because arguments is missconfigured. This is only two strings: ['pim_catalog_simpleselect', 'pim_reference_data_simpleselect'] and this is service and parameter : ['@pim_catalog_simpleselect', '%pim_reference_data_simpleselect%']

Comment: `pim_catalog_simpleselect` and `pim_reference_data_simpleselect` are part of my array parameter that I want to overide. There is no misconfigured arguments here and the service declaration is in a package that I used and that works properly (whence my desire to override it with a compiler pass). The first service parameter is visible in the parent service : `@pim_connector.array_converter.flat_to_standard.product.field_splitter` Thanks for you replies but you misunderstand my problem.

Comment: The problem is that when I retrieve my arguments with the method `getArguments()` I only retrieve my array of strings but not the service present in the parent service declaration. This is why I can't replace it because the first argument in the reality is not my array of string but the service... You can see it in the service declaration and in the PHP class

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: If you want to understand properly my problem I create a small project with the bug https://github.com/FabienSalles/symfony-bug-on-compiler-pass